# BASH port knock with combination

Tags: bash, combinations

I am trying to use bash to generate a port knock with all possible combinations of {1..3}. I have spent the last 48 hours trying to come up with an answer and am finally looking for some assistance.

My current code is below:

```
#!/bin/bash
HOST=$1
COUNTER=0
while [ COUNTER -lt 100 ];do
    shift
    for PORT in "$@"
    do
        nmap -Pn --host_timeout 100 --max-retries 0 -p $PORT $HOST
let COUNTER=COUNTER+1
    done
done

#Syntax knock.sh x.x.x.x 1 2 3
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `shift ` be before the `while` loop?

Comment: Yes, that was a mistake on my part. I have also used  set={1..3} group=3  and modified the for loop as follows: for ((i=1; i<$group; i++)

Comment: What is "all possible combinations of {1..3}"?  And how does it correspond to the code you presented?  Are you talking about generating port numbers in a certain range?  Using only those digits (with repeats allowed?)?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you have this `COUNTER` but as far as I understand what you wanted, you probably:

- misplaced `shift`,
- misused `[]` (test) in your while condition,
- misplaced `let COUNTER=COUNTER+1`

Quick fix with minimal changes:

```
#!/bin/bash
HOST=$1
shift
COUNTER=0
while [ $COUNTER -lt 100 ]; do
    for PORT in "$@"
    do
        nmap -Pn --host_timeout 100 --max-retries 0 -p $PORT $HOST
    done
    let COUNTER=COUNTER+1
done
```

Personally, I would have written:

```
HOST=$1
shift
for (( COUNTER = 0; COUNTER < 100; COUNTER += 1 )); do
  for PORT in "$@"; do
    nmap -Pn --host_timeout 100 --max-retries 0 -p $PORT $HOST
  done
done
```

which I find easier to understand. Matter of taste. Remarks about your coding style: you should probably try to be consistent and chose between semi columns (your while loop) or line breaks (your for loop). And of course, correctly indent your code. It really helps.